# Handling cumulative sum of variable in time series modelling

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, cumulants

I would like to build a prediction model, based on the time series data, but all the features are a cumulative sum over the period. For example, the value of feature x is

50 at t = 1 (original value 50),
120 at t = 2 (original value 70),
130 at t = 3 (original value 10),

and so on. These data are taken every 5 minutes.

Is there any way to handle this situation effectively by using some statistical techniques? And I think simply taking the differences between them would be cumbersome. I would like to know a general way to handle the cumulative sum of the variables in time series data.

Comment: This paper seems to address a similar problem: 
https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/pdf/10.1287/mnsc.43.6.879

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach is to model the increment process (the first difference of the cumulative sum process) and then take a cumulative sum thereof. Cumulative sums are bound to have unit roots (this goes by definition), and such processes do not lend themselves easily to traditional statistical modelling because they (the processes) are nonstationary. Estimation techniques of statistical models typically require the processes to be stationary, otherwise the estimates of model parameters fail to have their nice properties (consistency, asymptotic normality) which is a hindrance for obtaining good quality forecasts.

So even though it may seem cumbersome, I suggest simply taking the first difference and working with it. The forecast of the first difference can then be added to the last observed value of the original process to obtain the forecast for the original process.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, what you mean by "forecast of the first difference can then be added to the last observed value of the original process to obtain the forecast for the original process".

Comment: Forecast of the first difference at time $t$ for time $t+1$ is the forecast of the change from the orginal variable from time $t$ to time $t+1$: $\widehat{\Delta y}_{t+1|t}=\hat y_{t+1}-y_t$. So if you want to get a forecast for the original variable at time $t+1$, $\hat y_{t+1|t}$, use $\hat y_{t+1|t}:=y_t+\widehat{\Delta y}_{t+1|t}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) one more thing, whether all time series models have an assumption of equally spaced time interval?

Comment: @user15025, All that I know of do.

Comment: Okay : ) I will see